# Как определить ID юзера в бот телеграм

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Есть код который обрабатывает команду юзера в бот телеграм. Хочу сделать чтобы он определял id пользователя который посылает команды

```
$bot->command('id', function ($message) use ($bot) {
    $answer = "тут вывести id юзера";
    $bot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), $answer);
});
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: `$answer = $message->getChat()->getId();`, в чем проблема?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie интересно почему не срабатывает условие `$id_user = $message->getChat()->getId();
    if ($id_user == мой id) { *** }`

Comment: объясните зачем вы сравниваете `id` пользователя который посылает команды с вашим `id`? С чего вы решили Что они совпадут? Вы самому себе пишете?

Comment: @Let’s say Pie, хочу сделать чтобы бот давал разные ответы для определенных id

Comment: ну так и делайте проверку на определенный `id`, а не сравнивайте со своим.

Comment: @Let’s say Pie, так я хочу седлать чтобы он выдавал мне (моему id) другие ответы... или я вас не правильно понял?